# How do I use conditional rendering on template tag?

Tags: vue.js

According to the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt) I should be able to add the v-if condition to the `<template>` tag:

```
<template v-if="false">
  <div>Invisible text</div>
</template>
```

But this will not hide the element, however it does work when added to the child element:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="false">Invisible text</div>
</template>
```

Any suggestions?

I'm including the template in another .vue file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <H1 class= "main-title">Title</H1>
    <span class="components">
      <testtemplate></testtemplate>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: If the `v-if` conditional is false, it's not added to DOM Tree. So if the `<template>` is missing from the Dom Tree there might be unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `template` tag of a [single-file component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) is not rendered by Vue like normal `<template>` tags. It is simply one of the placeholders, along with `<script>` and `<style>` that [`vue-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-loader) uses to build the component. The root element of that `template` is what will be the root in the component.

But, even if it worked the way you want, there would be no difference between your first and second example. Using `v-if` on the root will prevent the entire component's template from rendering if set to `false`.

Comment: I can confirm that the behavior that Mikko shares here is real. Vue does NOT treat his first and second example as equal.

Answer (score 7):

Had this problem with VUE3. Using [SFC](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/single-file-component.html) just nest tag *template* inside another tag *template* :

```
<template>
    <template v-if="false">
     You won't see this
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this happened to me too. It sucks having to add one more level of indentation, but it worked.