# v-if on a component template tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt):

> Because v-if is a directive, it has to be attached to a single
> element. But what if we want to toggle more than one element? In this
> case we can use v-if on a  element, which serves as an
> invisible wrapper. The final rendered result will not include the
>  element.

But on my template in my component:

```
<template v-if="false">
    <div>
       ....
    </div>
</template>
```

But the component still renders.

I ask because I want a hook on the component so if v-if is true, I can do some code in `beforeMounted` and `beforeDestroyed` if false.

Comment: group components you want to conditionally render into parent component and then add v-if to parent component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use conditional rendering on template tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181741/how-do-i-use-conditional-rendering-on-template-tag)

Answer (score 1):

If I undestood what are you doing...

You're putting v-if int the template tag ina `.vue` file right?
Like this

```
// component.vue
<template v-if="false">
   <div>
     My Component
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
     name: 'my-component'
};
</script>
<styles>
</styles>
```

Right?

If YES, you are doing it wrong.

The template there is a tag for Webpack Vue Loader to load the component template.

So the `if` must go inside the template tag.

```
// component.vue
<template>
   <div v-if="false">
     My Component
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
     name: 'my-component'
};
</script>
<styles>
</styles>
```

If you need to "hide" multiple elements, just encapsulate into another `div`.

Comment: conditional if can be used [on a template](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt)

Answer (score 1):

Your reference to the docs is correct, you can use a `v-if` on a template tag. However, I believe conditionals on the top-level `<template>` in a Single File Component are ignored.

To achieve the effect showed in the docs (conditional render a template) *that* template needs to be within the top-level template section.

Example:

```
<script>
// your script section
</script>
<template>
  
  <template v-if="false">
    <div>
       ....
    </div>
  </template>

</template>
<style>
// your style section
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Lucas Katayama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1181036/lucas-katayama) said, you cannot use `v-if` inside SFC, but another way to hide you component is use `v-if` on this component in its parent component.