# v-if not working on template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I am relatively new to learning Vue.js. I have gotten to understand most of it so far but I still have trouble with v-if never working. For example...

I would expect these to not show because showProgress is false!

```
<template v-if="showProgress">
  <div id="progressCols" class="md-layout">
    <div class="md-layout-item" :class="[{ activeStep: currentStep(1) }, '.md-elevation-1']"></div>
    <div class="md-layout-item" :class="[{ activeStep: currentStep(2) }, '.md-elevation-1']"></div>
    <div class="md-layout-item" :class="[{ activeStep: currentStep(3) }, '.md-elevation-1']"></div>
    <div class="md-layout-item" :class="[{ activeStep: currentStep(4) }, '.md-elevation-1']"></div>
    <div class="md-layout-item" :class="[{ activeStep: currentStep(5) }, '.md-elevation-1']"></div>
    {{ showProgress }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'ProgressCols',
    data: function(){
      return {
        showProgress: false 
      }
    },
    methods: {
      currentStep(i){
        let n = 0;
        if (this.$route.params.name == "Ailments") {
          n =  1; 
        } else if (this.$route.params.name == "Effects") {
          n =  2; 
        }

        i < n ? true : false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The `template` tags are special, it'll work on anything else though!

Comment: You can inline the template in your component: `{ template: '<div>Hello</div>', ... }` *without any* `<template>`-tags. So I think the tags are there for mainly two reasons: To help the parser easily find start and end of your template. and to help your IDE with syntax highlighting. You can do `<template lang="jade">` when you use other things than html, but that is (probably?) also the only usable attribute on the template-tag.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47459404/104380

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `v-if` should be on the outermost `div`, not `template`.

```
<template>
  <div id="progressCols" class="md-layout" v-if="showProgress">
    <div class="md-layout-item" :class="[{ activeStep: currentStep(1) }, '.md-elevation-1']"></div>
    <div class="md-layout-item" :class="[{ activeStep: currentStep(2) }, '.md-elevation-1']"></div>
    <div class="md-layout-item" :class="[{ activeStep: currentStep(3) }, '.md-elevation-1']"></div>
    <div class="md-layout-item" :class="[{ activeStep: currentStep(4) }, '.md-elevation-1']"></div>
    <div class="md-layout-item" :class="[{ activeStep: currentStep(5) }, '.md-elevation-1']"></div>
    {{ showProgress }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    name: 'ProgressCols',
    data: function(){
      return {
        showProgress: false 
      }
    },
    methods: {
      currentStep(i){
        let n = 0;
        if (this.$route.params.name == "Ailments") {
          n =  1; 
        } else if (this.$route.params.name == "Effects") {
          n =  2; 
        }

        i < n ? true : false
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Without a `v-else` on the template, it doesn't know what to render when false.

Comment: Thank a lot! You saved my day! Because in the docs it's been said that it's ok to use `template` + `v-if` which is not true...

Comment: conditional `if` **can** [be used on a template](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt)

Comment: @vsync I think the point of the question (and the reason I got here much later) is that the docs say that is supported but it isn't working... in my case even with a v-else on a separate template as the docs show. What isn't clear from the docs is that it works if used on template tags that are not the outermost template.

Comment: Jesus the Vue docs is *really* outdated. Just yesterday I found out that `watch()` is only deep by default for `reactive()`, while in the docs they use the literal word "reactive" which implies both `ref()` and `reactive()`. And now this.